# Returning a pointer to a structure and accessing its fields C++

Tags: c++

I am implementing a skiplist for my self and I'm experiencing some problems with C++.
I have two structures:

1. A node of the skiplist - it holds its int value, and a pointer to an array of pointers to other nodes.

   ```
   struct node{
       int val;
       node** next;
   };
   ```
2. Skiplist which holds pointers to the head and tail of the list (sentinels).

   ```
   struct skiplist{
       node *head, *tail;
   };
   ```

Also, I have a function which returns a pointer to the skiplist structure (I use this function to initialize the skiplist):

```
skiplist* createSkipList(){
    skiplist* l = new skiplist;
    node* listHead = new node;
    node* listTail = new node;

    node* headNext[MAX_LEVEL]; //array of pointers
    listHead->next = headNext;

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_LEVEL; i++){
        listHead->next[i] = listTail;
    }

    l->head=listHead;
    l->tail=listTail;
}
```

And in the main() function I call:

```
skiplist* skiplist=createSkipList();
```

Everything works fine in the `createSkipList()` function, but if I want to refer to the skiplist in the main() i.e. by accessing `skiplist->tail` the program crashes. 
I've been searching for related posts, but they didn't help me.

As mentioned [in a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632455/c-function-return-pointer-to-struct-goes-weird) I should't experience dangling pointers because I am using the `new` operator to allocate the structures.
I would be grateful for any hints ;)

Comment: You don't `return l;` from `createSkiplist()`.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and stop wasting your time and everyone else's. The compiler would have told you about the missing return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First problem:**

You are not returning anything from `createSkipList()`, which means your program has undefined behavior. Add a `return` statement:

```
skiplist* createSkipList(){
    skiplist* l = new skiplist;
    // ...
    return l;
//  ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Per paragraph 6.6.3/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined
>   behavior in a value-returning function.

**Second problem:**

> As mentioned in a similar post I should't experience dangling pointers because I am using the new operator to allocate the structures [...]

Unfortunately, you do experience dangling pointers. As mentioned by Angew [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495794/returning-a-pointer-to-a-structure-and-accessing-its-fields-c#comment23676665_16495812), what you are doing here:

```
node* headNext[MAX_LEVEL]; //array of pointers
listHead->next = headNext;
```

Is to create a *local* array object and let `listHead->next` point to its first element, without considering that the array (as well as the objects it contains) will be destroyed once `createSkipList()` returns - objects with automatic storage duration get destroyed when they fall out of scope.

Moreover, as a general advice, consider using smart pointers for modeling ownership rather than doing manual memory management through raw pointers, `new`, and `delete`.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that `listHead->next` is set to point to a local variable and will become dangling once the function exits.

Comment: @Angew: Correct, I stopped at the first problem ;) Thank you for mentioning it, I am going to add it to the answer

Comment: @First problem
I was inattentive enough to omit the return statement in my code snippet. Of course you're right and thank you for commenting on that.

@Second problem:
I've changed the line in which I create the array, and now it works fine. Thank you both for helping me on that ;)
In case somebody experienced similar problem:
`node** headNext = new node*[MAX_LEVEL];`
Now the array will not be lost after the function exits.